# cannot change file permissions on Android Virtual Device (AVD)

Tags: android, file, permissions, virtual, device

I am unable to change permissions on a shell script I need to test on an Android Virtual Device (AVD).  The AVD is Google Pixel 2 (API 29) - it was created via Android Studio.  Using Android Debug Bridge (adb) from Android SDK on a MacBook, I did:

%adb push file.sh /sdcard/steve

The file.sh script is executable (mode 755) on the MacBook, but when it gets pushed onto the AVD, the mode goes to 660 (i.e. no longer executable).  So then I do:

%adb shell

which opens up an emulator shell session.  I then proceed in the AVD shell session as follows:

%generic_x86: cd /sdcard/steve
%generic_x86: chmod +x file.sh
This yields no error message and actually no message at all.  There is no change to the permissions for file.sh. It remains not executable.
 Do I need to push the file to a different directory on the AVD? Or is there some other way to make me able to change file permissions once it is pushed onto the AVD (emulator)?
 Note: I have looked at the Android Studio "Device File Explorer" where one can create files and directories on the AVD, however, one cannot change permissions on the files. 
TIA for any tips,
Steve

Comment: You know that read and write acces for the path you mentioned is blocked for Android Q? I do not understand that you manage to create a directory /sdcard/steve.

Comment: Apparently not - after "adb shell",

Comment: Apparently it's not blocked for this AVD, Google Pixel 2 - after "adb shell", I did -- %generic_x86: cd /sdcard, %generic_x86: mkdir steve,  and the directory is created.  Then as I said, I was able to do "adb push .." of a file to /sdcard/steve.  But, cannot change permissions on this file.  Should I be using a different directory on the AVD?

Comment: Dont know. The restrictions under Q do not apply for getFilesDIr(), getExternalFilesDir() and getExternalFilesDirs(). So you could try there.

Comment: OK - that's good to know.  Since I'm not at the coding stage yet, it would be great to know what dirs those procedures you reference are touching.

Comment: Those are app specific directories. You have no app indeed. Then there will be no difference. Useless to try.

Comment: OK - gotcha.  I was hoping to do some pre-coding script tests, but it definitely looks like it's app development time.  Of course, I more than welcome anybody who can clue me in as to a way to successfully do chmod in the emulator from the command line.  (note: I saw a post where someone suggested doing "su" in the emulator, but this binary does not exist with this AVD.)

Answer (score 1):

OK - I seemed to have solved this via what I would call circuitous means.  As mentioned earlier, I can push a file to my AVD via: 
%adb push file.sh /sdcard/steve

The problem was then I could not change permissions on this file.  I found out the command "run-as (classname)" gave me the ability to do a chmod.  So the sequence is this: 
    

    `%adb push file.sh /sdcard/steve`
    `%generic_x86:run-as com.example.helloworld`
    `%generic_x86:cd /data/data/com.example.helloworld`
    `%generic_x86:mkdir steve`
    %generic_x86:cd steve
    %generic_x86:cp /sdcard/steve/file.sh .
    %generic_x86:chmod +x file.sh

Now I'm off to the races.  Interestingly, the one location on the AVD I can push files to is /sdcard.  Thanks to "blackapps" for your inputs.